# useQuery : not getting data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

when I am logging the data its undefined but when I log inside then I see data. Any idea why?

`const {data}= useQuery('get-todos',()=>{axios.get('http://localhost:8080/todos').then(res =>  res.data)})`

Comment: The second parameter given to `useQuery` is a function that does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

your query function needs to return the promise from axios:

```
const {data}= useQuery('get-todos',() => {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/todos').then(res => res.data)
})
```